# error with Powershell PnP command for new pnp site

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

(cross posted at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/279200/errors-with-new-pnp-site-command)

Running the Windows PowerShell ISE as administrator with `Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -verbose`.

I'm connected to the SharePoint online site. Using `get-pnptenantsite` works fine.

I issue the following command:

```
New-PnPSite -Type TeamSite -Title "Aaa aaa" -Alias "aaaa" -Owners "me@mydomain.com,someone@mydomain.com" -Lcid 5129
```

It sits for ten minutes, then comes back with the error.

```
New-PnPSite : OfficeDevPnP.Core.Sites.SiteCollection.CreateAsync: Could not create team site.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-PnPSite -Type TeamSite -Title "Aaa aaa" -Alias "aaaa" -Owners "me ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [New-PnPSite], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.NewSite
```

I try with fewer owners and no Lcid.

```
New-PnPSite -Type TeamSite -Title "Aaa aaa" -Alias "aaaa" -Owners "me@mydomain.com"
```

It immediately comes back with the error that the group alias exists:

```
New-PnPSite : {"error":{"code":"-2147024713, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":"The group alias already exists."}}
At line:1 char:1
+ New-PnPSite -Type TeamSite -Title "Aaa aaa" -Alias "aaaa" -Owners "me ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [New-PnPSite], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.NewSite
```

Why does that alias exist? It just told me it couldn't create it.

So I try again with a different alias:

```
New-PnPSite -Type TeamSite -Title "BBB aaa" -Alias "bbbb" -Owners "me@mydomain.com"
```

Now I get the error

```
New-PnPSite : {"error":{"code":"-1, System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException","message":"{\"odata.error\":{\"code\":\"Request_BadRequest\",\"me
ssage\":{\"lang\":\"en\",\"value\":\"One or more added object references already exist for the following modified properties: 'owners'.\"}}}"}}
At line:1 char:1
+ New-PnPSite -Type TeamSite -Title "BBB aaa" -Alias "bbbb" -Owners "me ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [New-PnPSite], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.NewSite
```

What am I doing wrong? Will it be faster to create two dozen sites manually through the admin center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem is the Lcid parameter. With the parameter `-Lcid 5129` the site fails to create.

The Office 365 group has already been created at this point, which causes the repeat command to fail.

And the Owners parameter should NOT contain the account running the command. This is not obvious from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Error:” One or more added object references already exist for the following modified properties: 'owners'”,you could change a SharePoint User to create the site.

Test result:
[image]